# How to create a pattern using for loops in C

Tags: c, design-patterns

I have been stumped by this problem. I need to create a pattern such as:

```
1
21
221
2221
22221
```

Using nested for loops. I have something that does (A)

```
222221
222221
222221
222221
222221
```

and used to have something that did (B)

/*    1
 *   21
 *   221
 *   2221
 *   22221
 *   222221
 *   2222222
 */

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    int n, c, k;

    printf("Enter number of rows\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    for ( c = 1 ; c <= n ; c++ )
    {
        printf("1\n");

        for( k = 1 ; k <= c ; k++ )
        printf("2");


    }

    return 0;
}
```

Any hints would be helpful.

Solution - Thanks to the intelligent people that decided to help.
I appreciate your help!

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    int n, c, k;

    printf("Enter number of rows");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    for ( c = 1 ; c <= n ; c++ )
    {


        for( k = 1 ; k < c ; k++ )
        {
            printf("2");
        }

        printf("1\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Show some code.

Comment: Smells like homework....

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII There's nothing wrong with homework here; note that that tag has been deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using nested for loops. Let's examine the formulae for one line of the output:

**line 1**:

> 1

Which can be made using a simple for loop like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
{
    putc('1', stdout);
    putc('\n', stdout);
}
```

**line 2**:

> 21

Hmm, this requires change to our structure, as we can't break the output of iteration #1, but we still need to be able to add the '2' in there... Something like this should work:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    if (i > 0)
       putc('2', stdout);

    putc('1', stdout);
    putc('\n', stdout);
}
```

**line 3:**

> 221

Wait, now we need two '2's in there! How can we do this without breaking line's 2 and three? Well something like this should do it:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
 {
     int j = i;
     while (j--)
     {
         putc('2', stdout);
     }

     putc('1', stdout);
     putc('\n', stdout);
 }
```

Notice that I used a `while` loop instead of a for loop. It is an exercise to the reader to figure out how to turn that while loop into a for loop.

Hopefully this helped you to understand the process behind solving similar problems like this in the future - as it is an important programming skill to have.

Comment: I honestly haven't slept because I've been trying to figure this out. Thank you all for your help. It is 8:25 AM. I won't rest till I finish.

Comment: I think the important programming skill is to look at the problem, abstract it as  "0 to 4 '2's followed by a '1'", and then write the obvious code that implements that.

Comment: @JimBalter that's a matter of style. For me personally, I think of the solution better while digging through the code, not just abstracting it outside of code. Everyone thinks differently, though, so what works for one may not work for another.

Comment: What you are talking about is a matter of *approach*, not "style", but if one *cannot* do the abstraction then one lacks the skill. And the entire direction of modern programming, functional programming, is toward this skill. It's remarkable how many C dinosaurs lack it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code that generates your first pattern.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define NUMLINES 5

int main(void) {
    int i, j;
    for(i=0; i<NUMLINES; i++) {
        for(j=0; j<i; j++) {
             printf("2");
        }
        printf("1\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The important part is that the inner `for` loops until the current value of the outer loop is reached (`j<i`).

Comment: You know the crazy part? I had everything there except the last printf statement was before the inner for.